# Eclipse breakpoints being hit even when choosing "Run" rather than "Debug"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

If I have breakpoints in some java code, they get hit even when I select "Run" rather than "Debug".  Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Eclipse can run several instances of the same program at one time.  Are you sure you do not by accident work with a previous instance which was run in Debug mode?

Comment: Are you using junit here, or running an application? And which version of Eclipse are we talking about here? What exactly are you doing to run the application? (Are you using F11 or selecting Run As ?)

Comment: It happens both in JUnit and with a main(String args[]) application.

I am using F11, but the same behavior happens with Run As, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not the expected behaviour, and I've never seen that happen on any version of Eclipse I've used.

Are you sure that you're really seeing what you think you're seeing? Perhaps you have the *debug* process still running and that's where the breakpoints are being hit rather than in the new *run* process.

Comment: If that's really the case then you've run into an Eclipse bug that no one else has seen before. It's more likely that you've made a mistake in what you think you're seeing, but since we can't see your screen, there's not much more we can do to help resolve that.